# need hlelp with for-each and array java

Tags: java

Write a static method method call longCount, which is passed an array of strings, and which returns the number of strings in the array that are more than 10 characters long (and thus the method return type is int). You must use a for-each loop in your solution.

This is what I came up with although it is still not compiling when I submit it.

```
public static int longCount(int[] data){
  int count = 0;
  for(int n : data){ 
  if(data[n]>10)
  count++;
}
  return count;
}
```

Comment: `if(data[n]>10)` You don't want `data[n]` here, you want `n`.  `n` isn't an index into the array, it's an element from the array.

Comment: Your method is supposed to accept a `String[]`, not an `int[]`.

Comment: `data[n]` would have worked if `n` was used as the index for the loop. Edit : Derp, it wouldn't throw a compile error anyway, just a false result (or an Index out of bound exception if n < 0...)

Comment: You don't even tell us the compiler error message.

Answer (score 7):

Your method is supposed to accept a `String[]`, not an `int[]`. That's probably what's causing the compiler error (but it's hard to tell, since you don't report the error message.) Also, the `for`-`each` loop for arrays binds the loop variable to each array *value*, not each index. I'd rewrite your method as:

```
public static int longCount(String[] data) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String s : data){ 
        if (s.length() > 10) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

To guard against array elements being `null`, you might consider changing the `if` condition to

```
if (s != null && s.length() > 10) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if(data[n]>10)
```

to

```
if(n>10)
```

with the [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) you get the *value* (not the *index*).

Comment: This may be true, but it wouldn't cause a *compile* error.